# Query problem using sembast (NoSql) with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nosql, sembast

I'm very new to NoSql databases, and I just want to ask you an easy question about the use of sembast! I'm developing a very simple app with flutter, and I want to get the object inside the array "list" with the "name" equal to 1.

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "list": [{
        "name": 1,
        "element": [{
            "nameItem": "a"
        }, {
            "nameItem": "b"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": 2,
        "element": []
    }, {
        "name": 3,
        "element": []
    }]
}
```

So I want to make a query that retrieves me this information:

```
{
    "name": 1,
    "element": [{
        "nameItem": "a"
    }, {
        "nameItem": "b"
    }]
}
```

I've written this code, but it doesn't work: I don't understand how to make a query with a subtag as a key in the json tree.

```
  Future<List<ElementList>> getElementFromList(int name) async{
    final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.equals("name", name));
    final recordSnapshot = await _elementList.find(await _db, finder: finder);
    return recordSnapshot.map((snapshot){
      final elementObj = ElementList.fromJson(snapshot.value);
      return elementObj;
    }).toList();
  }
```

this returns me []. How can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sembast queries allow to filter records, not part of a record. If the object you mention is a whole record, you can:

- use custom filter to perform the lookup yourself for each record in the database (checking each item in the `list` field`)
- when a record is retrieved, extract the item (doing a similar Map/List manipulation)

See [an issue with a complex filtering](https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/issues/152)